# Не могу подключиться к серверу, не понял как сделать

Tags: ssh, openvpn

У меня ubuntu16.04.

Мне предоставили файлы: .ovpn, два .crt, .key.

Просто подключаясь, через `ssh` - ssh `user@host`.

Выдает ошибку -  `Resource temporarily unavailable`.

Можете помочь, что нужно сделать или какую информацию искать.

Впервые сталкиваюсь с таким. Не могу задать правильный вопрос, чтобы найти необходимую  информацию.

Comment: Зачем же Вы удалили предыдущий идентичный вопрос =((( Я так долго писал Вам ответ, в итоге пришлось всё удалить.

Comment: В общем, если в кратце - то Вам надо запустить файл .ovpn дабы установить все настройки. Далее запустить сам vpn. Затем указать пути к сертификатам и можно подключаться.

Comment: Сделал то, что  говорил. Появилось несколько Ip.Локальный, wifi и также новый eth2. При подключение по ssh сделал маску -b. Идет подключение, ввожу пароль ответа нету, просто не отвечает. Если пароль ввожу не правильный, тогда ответ приходит быстро, что было отказано